# How do I easily combine elements from two arrays in Javascript, alternating elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have two arrays in JavaScript, of potentially different lengths:

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
```

I'd like to combine them into one array:

```
var z = ['a', 'g', 'b', 'h', 'c', 'i', 'j'];
```

How can I do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: `z = _.flatten(_.zip(x, y)).filter(element => element)`, as long as you don't care about *null* elements in the original arrays.

---

Some of the libraries providing functional tools, such as [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), provide enough mechanics to easily do this. For example, you can do this:

```
var z1 = _.zip(x, y);
// z1 is now [["a","g"],["b","h"],["c","i"],[null,"j"]]

var z2 = _.flatten(z1);
// z2 is now ["a","g","b","h","c","i",null,"j"]

var z3 = z2.filter(element => element)
// z3 is now ["a","g","b","h","c","i","j"]
```

Note that this will only work if the original arrays do not contain any null elements, as they are filtered out by the last step.

Answer (score 7):

I see you answered your question at the same time as asking it. That's fine, but it's now clear that you were looking for a solution that leverages a library (eg, lodash) and not necessarily one that teaches you how to build such a procedure. In retrospect, I would've answered this differently, but nevertheless I think you can learn something from this answer.

---

I would recommend calling this something other than `zip` just because `zip` is used as name for a procedure that does something quite different from what you're looking for.

Here's a simple recursive definition of `interleave` -

```js
const interleave = ([ x, ...xs ], ys = []) =>
  x === undefined
    ? ys                             // base: no x
    : [ x, ...interleave (ys, xs) ]  // inductive: some x

const xs = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
  
const ys = [ 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ]

console .log (interleave (xs, ys))
// [ a, g, b, h, c, i, j ]
```

And another variation that supports any number of input arrays -

```js
const interleave = ([ x, ...xs ], ...rest) =>
  x === undefined
    ? rest.length === 0
      ? []                                // base: no x, no rest
      : interleave (...rest)              // inductive: no x, some rest
    : [ x, ...interleave (...rest, xs) ]  // inductive: some x, some rest

const ws = [ '0', '1', '2', '3' ]

const xs = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

const ys = [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ]

const zs = [ 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ]

console .log (interleave (ws, xs, ys, zs))
// [ 0, a, d, g, 1, b, e, h, 2, c, f, i, 3, j ]
```

Comment: Pretty cool. I improved upon your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40406555/783743

Comment: it does not work with `undefined` as value of an array.

Comment: Correct, `undefined` is for *undefined* behaviour. If you use `undefined` values, expect ... *undefined* behaviour. If you want to leave holes in the array, use `null` values – that's my personal philosophy anyway.

Comment: There's many empty types `0`, `''`, `[]`, `{}` etc, but `null` is used for an untyped empty value. However, `undefined` is provides even less information – it is neither typed or empty. Relying on some behaviour for `undefined` is wrong imo, and even worse to try to write code that defends against it. Instead `undefined` should be left for the programmer to use how they want rather than allowing it to serve as a broken representation of some user data.

Comment: ok, just to mention this behaviour with `undefined`, so no offence.

Comment: Indeed, good answers. I *was* looking for a straightforward answer to the problem, since this is for real-world code, so using libraries was a better choice in our case because we didn't want to re-invent the wheel. But your answer is better to help understand how this would actually be solved using pure JS. Thorough. Thanks.

Comment: This method is unreadable, plus the syntax is not respecting standard. I would opt for more concise and more beautifully written answers on this page.

Comment: @vdegenne sadly you are trapped in a prison of black/white thinking. different syntax styles open up new ways to express programs. i wish you the best.

Answer (score 3):

A simple implementation that will stitch the arrays:

```js
function stitch(x, y) {
  var arr = [];
  var length = Math.max(x.length, y.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    i < x.length && arr.push(x[i]);
    i < y.length && arr.push(y[i]);
  }
  
  return arr;
}

var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

console.log(stitch(x, y));
```

Comment: That's slightly neater than my solution in the sense that it handles nulls, thanks!

Comment: @Endless - indeed. I'll use that :)

Comment: i might not call this `zip` only because that name is commonly used as a procedure that does something quite different.

Comment: A `zip` function would return something like `[['a', 'g'], ['b', 'h'], ['c', 'i']];`, you should name it differently

Comment: @naomik - thanks. I've changed the name to stitch, as zip is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

This is the functional way to address the problem:

```
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

function stitch(x,y) {

var a = x.length > y.length ? x : y;
var b = x.length > y.length ? y : x;

var c = a.map(function (e, i) {
    return b.length<i ? [e, b[i]] : [];
});

return [].concat.apply([],c)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple recursive solution:

```js
const interlace = (xxs, ys) => {
    if (xxs.length === 0) return ys;
    const  [x, ...xs] = xxs;
    return [x, ...interlace(ys, xs)];
};

const xs = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const ys = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

console.log(JSON.stringify(interlace(xs, ys)));
```

In addition, you can easily generalize this algorithm to an arbitrary number of arrays:

```js
const interlace = (...xss) => xss.length > 0 ? interleave(...xss) : [];

const interleave = (xxs, ...yss) => {
    if (xxs.length === 0) return interlace(...yss);
    const  [x, ...xs] = xxs;
    return [x, ...interleave(...yss, xs)];
};

const xs = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const ys = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
const zs = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

console.log(JSON.stringify(interlace()));
console.log(JSON.stringify(interlace(xs)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(interlace(xs, ys)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(interlace(xs, ys, zs)));
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in regular Javascript. No need for fancy tricks:

```js
function splicer(array, element, index) {
    array.splice(index * 2, 0, element);
    return array;
}

function weave(array1, array2) {
    return array1.reduce(splicer, array2.slice());
}

var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

var z = weave(x, y);

console.log(z);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var y = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];

var z=[];
if(y.length>=x.length){
  for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    z.push(x[i]);
    z.push(y[i]);
  }
  while(i<y.length)
    z.push(y[i++]);
  
}else{
  for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++){
    z.push(x[i]);
    z.push(y[i]);
  }
  while(i<x.length)
    z.push(x[i++]);  
}

window.alert(JSON.stringify(z)); // print ["a","g","b","h","c","i","j"]
```